# Producer and consumer thread working unexpectedly

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

**main thread**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> taskQueue = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int MAX_CAPACITY = 5;
        Producer pt=new Producer(taskQueue,MAX_CAPACITY);
        Consumer ct=new Consumer(taskQueue);
        pt.start();
        ct.start();
    }
```

**Producer Thread**

```
public class Producer<T> extends Thread {

    private final List<Integer> taskQueue;
    private final int Max_CAPACITY;

    public Producer(List<Integer> taskQueue,int size) {
        this.taskQueue = taskQueue;
        this.Max_CAPACITY=size;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int count = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                produce(count++);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void produce(int i) throws InterruptedException {

        synchronized (taskQueue){
            while(taskQueue.size()==Max_CAPACITY){
                System.out.println("taskQueue is full wait some time for removal");
                taskQueue.wait();
            }

            Thread.sleep(100);
            taskQueue.add(i);

            System.out.println("produced "+i);
            taskQueue.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

**Consumer Thread**

```
public class Consumer<T> extends Thread {

    private final List<Integer> taskQueue;

    Consumer(List<Integer> taskQueue) {
        this.taskQueue = taskQueue;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            try {
                consume();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void consume() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (taskQueue) {

            while(taskQueue.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println("taskQueue is empty..wait for adding items");
                taskQueue.wait();
            }
            Thread.sleep(100);
           int removal= taskQueue.remove(0);
            System.out.println("consumed.. "+removal);
            taskQueue.notifyAll();


        }
    }
}
```

According to the concept:

`Wait()` and `notify()` method are called on the object.Here `taskqueue` is the common object.
Suppose `Producer` thread got the chance first and get hold the lock of `taskqueue` object. On adding the value in the `taskqueue` it call the `notifyAll()`.But  no `wait()` is called on `Consumer` thread (as queue is not empty) so `notifyAll()` has no use for Consumer. Again, just assuming that consumer will just resume and remove the element from `taskqueue` and call the `notifyAll()` and now again, `producer` thread has no use of consumer `notifyAll()` as no `wait()` is called on producer either. So how this producer-consumer working?

**In short**, If `wait()` is not called on the producer, then how the producer thread resume its working even after the consumer thread call the `notifyAll()`. How the producer get notified about the Consumer thread if there in Producer, no `wait()` is called?

OUTPUT:

```
produced 0
produced 1
produced 2
produced 3
produced 4
taskQueue is full wait some time for removal
consumed.. 0
consumed.. 1
consumed.. 2
consumed.. 3
consumed.. 4
taskQueue is empty..wait for adding items
produced 5
produced 6
produced 7
produced 8
produced 9
taskQueue is full wait some time for removal
consumed.. 5
consumed.. 6
consumed.. 7
consumed.. 8
consumed.. 9
```

it will keep going like that...

**UPDATE:**

Assume producer thread got the chance first. then it print(produce)

```
produced 0
produced 1
produced 2
produced 3
produced 4
```

After that `taskequeue` become full and `wait()` is called on producer,
so now consumer thread got the chance and as soon as consumer thread consume the element
`consume 0` . `notify()` is called, so now producer thread that was was on waiting state get notification and resume. so now producer should
produce 5
produce 6 and so on. **But instead consumer thread still running and printing**

```
consume 2
consume 3
```

How this happening? Hope now it is clear what i meant.
**All i want the justification of this output. how it is printing**

Comment: What do you think would prevent the consumer thread from running? If you don't want the consumer thread to run, you need to make sure that something stops it. Nothing does that in this code.

Answer (score 2):

`notifyAll` always returns immediately. (and so does `notify`, for that matter).

`notifyAll` It will 'break out' anything that has called `wait` on the same object, but that doesn't mean those threads immediately proceed to run the code that follows the `obj.wait()` invocation. If there are no such threads, okay, then nothing happens.

`notify` is the same thing, except instead of breaking out all of them, it breaks an arbitrary one, and if there are none, then nothing happens.

The reason the other threads don't immediately start running is that they first need to re-acquire the lock (they're in a `synchronized(obj)` block; they 'drop' that lock when wait starts, they need to re-acquire it before wait can end.

Comment: yes. you are right. But  according to my code explaination, wait() will not be called. so how the elements from the taskqueue keep adding and removing at all. How this code working fine like normal PD code?

Comment: @kungfu: The *only* purpose of notifyAll is to wake up waiting threads. If no threads are waiting, there is nothing to notify. The check for full or empty queue gets skipped and the code proceeds to do its add/removal stuff.

Comment: @kungfu I don't understand your confusion then. I grokked your question as essentially asking: "Shouldn't notifyAll take forever, given that there is nothing waiting", and the answer is: No, notifyAll ALWAYS returns immediately, regardless of circumstances - because if there's nothing waiting, then notifyAll simply doesn't do anything (not just 'for this code', no, 'for all imaginable scenarios'). If I didn't understand your question perhaps update it.

Comment: @rzwitserloot. can you please look at my update section . I will highly appreciate.

Comment: It's one legal way to go through - consumer (the thread) is still running. yes, it has called notify, but as I said __notify does NOTHING AT ALL__ - not directly. I merely opens one of the two gates that need to be opened for a `wait` call to continue. The other gate that needs opening is the `synchronized` lock, which CANNOT immediately open, as whatever thread invoked `notifyAll` by definition has that on lock.